# Giving option "add more files" after "choose file" and listing names of all the files chosen before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, file-upload

Goal : After selecting "choose file" button i want to show the name of the files(f1.txt and f2.txt). After that i want to be able to click on the button again and list those along with previous ones(f1.txt, f2.txt, f3.txt and f4.txt). After this on clicking "upload files" i want to upload all 4 files.

I've tried hiding the previous buttons and all but without success on the other part. I came across this post which seemed helpful: *[List selected files from file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383459/list-selected-files-from-file-input)* . I've been at it for a week and decided to post this.

Below is the code for your reference.

P.S. I am a newbie in this field so please elaborate your answer.(Sorry for the mess)

```js
function restrictTypeAndSize(obj) {

  var s = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.files.length; i++) {
    s = writefiles(obj.files[i]);
  }
}

function writefiles(file) {

  if (file.type.indexOf("image") == -1 && file.type.indexOf("pdf") == -1) {
    alert("Invalid Type!");
    $("#fileAttachment").attr("src", "blank");
    document.getElementById("fileAttachment").value = "";
    return false;
  }

  if (file.size > 10485760) {
    alert("Individual Image size should not be greater than 10 Mb!");
    $("#fileAttachment").attr("src", "blank");
    document.getElementById("fileAttachment").value = "";
    return false;
  }
  var result = $('div#result');
  if (window.FileReader && window.Blob) {
    var file = file;
    console.log('Loaded file: ' + file.name);
    console.log('Blob mime: ' + file.type);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
      var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
      var header = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        header += arr[i].toString(16);
      }
      console.log('File header: ' + header);

      // Check the file signature against known types
      var type = 'unknown';
      switch (header) {
        case '89504e47':
          type = 'image/png';
          break;
        case 'ffd8ffe0':
        case 'ffd8ffe1':
        case 'ffd8ffe2':
          type = 'image/jpeg';
          break;
        case '25504446':
          type = 'application/pdf';
          break;
      }

      if (file.type !== type) {
        alert("File extension doesn't match the image type !");
        $("#fileAttachment").attr("src", "blank");
        document.getElementById("fileAttachment").value = "";
        console.log('Mime type detected: ' + type +
          '. Does not match file extension.');
      } else {
        console.log('Mime type detected: ' + type +
          '. Matches file extension.');
      }
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

  } else {
    result
      .html('<span style="color: red; ">Your browser is not supported. Sorry.</span>');
    console
      .error('FileReader or Blob is not supported by the browser.');
  }

}
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Servlet File Upload/Download</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div style="margin: 50px">
      <!-- <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family: garamond, serif ">File Upload</h1> -->
      <h2 style="text-align: center; color: black; font-family: courier">
        Welcome!
      </h2>
      <br>
      <form id="fileUploadForm" method="post" action="fileUploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form_group">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-0 col-form-label"><strong>User
                                Id :</strong></label>
            <div class="col-sm-0">
              <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticId" name="staticId" value="" style="font-family: courier">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><b><strong>Full Name :</strong></b></label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required style="font-family: courier">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleTextarea"><b><strong>File
                                    Description :</strong></b></label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3" style="font-family: courier" name="description"></textarea>
          </div>

          <label><i>Upload File</i></label><span id="colon">: </span><input id="fileAttachment" type="file" name="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, .pdf" onchange="restrictTypeAndSize(this)" /> <span id="fileUploadErr"><b><i><strong>Please Choose A File!</strong></i></b></span>
        </div>
        <button id="uploadBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return showAlert()">Upload</button>
      </form>
      <br> <br>
      <!-- List All Uploaded Files -->
      <div class="panel">
        <a id="allFiles" class="hyperLink" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/uploadedFilesServlet"><button
                        type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">List all
                        uploaded files</button></a>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <a id="fileUpload" class="hyperLink" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.jsp"><button
                        type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right">Logout</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Essentially, you will want to store your Files someplace, not as part of the File input. This way, you can append more files to the list. When the Form is submitted, you will need to build the file list as one to upload or upload in the background via AJAX.

Comment: What about the `multiple` attribute of an `<input type='file'>`? [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#additional_attributes) -- Keep it simple ;)

Comment: Twisty, as of now, after clicking "Upload" the files are sent to a servlet where they are stored in a server file system. I want to use only javascript for the time being. Thank you

Comment: Louys, please read the question, this isn't what I've asked for :)

Comment: @Manish I am aware and my suggestion was to be done in JavaScript. Store an array of your files, then the User can add more to that list before it is sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

From your post, it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish exactly. I understand the basics. It's just not clear what you have tried or what you want the User to do.

I started by cleaning up some of the code. Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function restrictTypeAndSize(o, t, s) {
    var r = [];
    if (t == undefined) {
      t = "image/jpeg";
    }
    if (s == undefined) {
      s = 10485760;
    }
    $.each(o.files, function(i, f) {
      if (t.indexOf(f.type) < 0) {
        r.push($.extend({}, f, {
          error: "Incorrect Type"
        }));
      } else if (f.size > s) {
        r.push($.extend({}, f, {
          error: "File Size"
        }));
      } else {
        writeFiles(f);
        r.push($.extend({}, f, {
          error: false
        }));
      }
    });
    return r;
  }

  function writeFiles(file) {
    var result = $('div#result');
    if (window.FileReader && window.Blob) {
      var file = file;
      console.log('Loaded file: ' + file.name);
      console.log('Blob mime: ' + file.type);

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
        var header = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          header += arr[i].toString(16);
        }
        console.log('File header: ' + header);

        // Check the file signature against known types
        var type = 'unknown';
        switch (header) {
          case '89504e47':
            type = 'image/png';
            break;
          case 'ffd8ffe0':
          case 'ffd8ffe1':
          case 'ffd8ffe2':
            type = 'image/jpeg';
            break;
          case '25504446':
            type = 'application/pdf';
            break;
        }

        if (file.type !== type) {
          alert("File extension doesn't match the image type !");
          $("#fileAttachment").attr("src", "blank");
          $("#fileAttachment").val("");
          console.log('Mime type detected: ' + type +
            '. Does not match file extension.');
        } else {
          console.log('Mime type detected: ' + type +
            '. Matches file extension.');
        }
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    } else {
      result
        .html('<span style="color: red; ">Your browser is not supported. Sorry.</span>');
      console
        .error('FileReader or Blob is not supported by the browser.');
    }
  }

  $("#fileAttachment").change(function(e) {
    var results = restrictTypeAndSize(this, $(this).attr("accept"));
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div style="margin: 50px">
    <h2 style="text-align: center; color: black; font-family: courier">Welcome!</h2>
    <br>
    <form id="fileUploadForm" method="post" action="fileUploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form_group">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-0 col-form-label"><strong>User Id :</strong></label>
          <div class="col-sm-0">
            <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticId" name="staticId" value="" style="font-family: courier">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><b><strong>Full Name :</strong></b></label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required style="font-family: courier">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleTextarea"><b><strong>File Description :</strong></b></label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3" style="font-family: courier" name="description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <label><i>Upload File</i></label><span id="colon">: </span><input id="fileAttachment" type="file" name="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf" /> <span id="fileUploadErr"><b><i><strong>Please Choose A File!</strong></i></b></span>
      </div>
      <button id="uploadBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return showAlert()">Upload</button>
    </form>
    <br> <br>
    <div class="panel">
      <a id="allFiles" class="hyperLink" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/uploadedFilesServlet"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">List all uploaded files</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <a id="fileUpload" class="hyperLink" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index.jsp"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right">Logout</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since you have `multiple` in your file input, the User can already add more than 1 file. It all seems to work yet I do not see where the selected files get stored locally so the User can then select more files. What should the User do at this point? How do they know what files they have selected already? What if they want to remove a file?

Comment: Thank you so much for this cleaner version. This is my code where i can add multiple files at once and submit them to a Servlet (I'm using Java and Tomcat server in Eclipse IDE). My problem is that if i click on choose file button again, the previous files get overwritten and only the newly selected files are being uploaded. I don't want this to happen.

Comment: Twisty, I've got code which does the work and saves the files in an array as you have said but submits them using ajax. I want them to submit using form post request itself. I don't have any idea how to adjust the code to my requirement. It will be a big help if you could help me out with this. This is the link to the code -- https://plnkr.co/edit/yTPAY41kZfhBD9kouoPQ?preview

Comment: @Manish you will have to rebuild the form data or append it before the form is posted. I will see if I can put together and example. Please update your OP with your current code example.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.

Comment: Twisty, I've finally solved it. I  created a hidden input field and a visible button. On clicking the button the input field was triggered and files were accepted. along with this i created a new input tag and "appendChild"-ed it and on the next button click this new input field was triggered and so on..